# How to stop loops or close figures in live scripts in matlab

Tags: matlab

I wanna use matlab **live scripts** to run a loop updating an animation because this will allow to playback the animation. In the normal command window or m files one can use uicontrol to stop loops or close figures. But this doesn't seem to work for live scripts because whenever 'figure' is called, a figure will pop up, then this animation can't be playbacked anymore. How to not pop up the figure/animation and stop the loop or close the animation in live scripts?

Comment: This is a Matlab-specific question. You'll get better answers on the Matlab-specific forums.

Comment: yes I tried but didn't get sth to help

Comment: Well, if you can't get help on the Matlab-specific forums, you're unlikely to get help anywhere else either.